# Pivot a 3 columns table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I am looking to pivot a data frame:

| index | Feature | value | SN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | table | A | 12345 |
| 1 | mix_ratio | 0.12 | 12345 |
| 2 | date | 2/2/2022 | 12345 |
| 0 | table | B | 12346 |
| 1 | mix_ratio | 0.15 | 12346 |
| 2 | date | 2/3/2022 | 12346 |
| 0 | table | C | 12347 |
| 1 | mix_ratio | 0.17 | 12347 |
| 2 | date | 2/4/2022 | 12347 |

The Pivot Result should be:

| SN | table | mix_ratio | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | A | 0.12 | 2/2/2022 |
| 12346 | B | 0.15 | 2/3/2022 |
| 12347 | C | 0.17 | 2/4/2022 |

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = df.pivot(index="SN", columns="Feature", values="value").reset_index()
df.columns.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      SN      date mix_ratio table
0  12345  2/2/2022      0.12     A
1  12346  2/3/2022      0.15     B
2  12347  2/4/2022      0.17     C
```